# Confusion Matrix query

Tags: python, pandas, confusion-matrix

I have the below code to generate the confusion Matrix where it generates **heatmap** and **accuracy_score**

**SOURCE**

[image]

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import metrics

data = pd.read_excel(r"\Confusion Matrix.xlsx")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(df['Actual'], df['Pred'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins = True)

sn.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()

accuray_score_in_percentage = accuracy_score(['Actual'], ['Pred'])
accuray_score_in_count = accuracy_score(['Actual'], ['Pred'], normalize=False)

print('The Precentage Accuracy is : ', accuray_score_in_percentage)
print('The Count of corrects are : ', accuray_score_in_count)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

From the above output you can see **The Precentage Accuracy is :  0.0** and **The Count of corrects are :  0** but it has to be **The Precentage Accuracy is :  0.3** and **The Count of corrects are :  3**. Can some one help me to modify the code so it shows me the correct **Accuracy Scores**.

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: When calling 'accuracy_score' you forgot to mention the dataframe. You've only mentioned the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the confusion matrix to compute accuracy.
Try :

```
accuray_score_in_percentage = accuracy_score(df['Actual'], df['Pred'])  
accuray_score_in_count = accuracy_score(df['Actual'], df['Pred'], normalize=False)
```

If you really want to use your confusion matrix, you can do :

```
accuray_score_in_percentage = (confusion_matrix.loc[0,0]+confusion_matrix.loc[1,1])/confusion_matrix.loc["All","All"]
accuray_score_in_count = confusion_matrix.loc[0,0]+confusion_matrix.loc[1,1]
```

Comment: I've replaced `accuray_score_in_percentage = accuracy_score(['Actual'], ['Pred'])` with `accuracy_score(confusion_matrix['Actual'], confusion_matrix['Pred'])` but throwing me error `**KeyError: Actual**`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my previous answer. I updated it.